# Jmeter Dynamic Json Array Generation from CSV file

Tags: json, csv, jmeter, load-testing

I have a following Json data to post.

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Zypher",
    "price": 12.50,
    "tags": [{
        "tag": 1,
        "tagName": "X"
    },
    {
        "tag": 2,
        "tagName": "Y"
    },
    {
        "tag": 2,
        "tagName": "Z"
    }]
}
```

My Jmeter Test Plan is as following,

```
- Test Plan
    - Thread Group
        - Http Request Defaults
        - Http Cookie Manager
        - Simple Controller
            - CSV Data Set Config (Sheet_1)
            - Http Header Manager
            - Http Request (The hard coded json was provided here as body data)
```

Every thing works fine. Now I want to use csv to parametrised my Json.

```
Sheet_1:
id,name,price
1,Zypher,12.50
```

I modified json with these 3 parameters and its works for me. Now I want to parametrise detail portion. I have no idea how to do this.
All I want to keep my json like this,

```
{
    "id": ${id},
    "name": ${name},
    "price": ${price},
    "tags": [
    {
        "tag": ${tag},
        "tagName": ${tagName}
    }]
}
```

How could I dynamically make json array `tags` for details portion from csv data? I want it to be looped as row provided in csv file.

Updated csv

```
id,name,price,tag,tagname
1,Zypher,12.50,7|9|11,X|Y|Z
```

It would be great in this format

```
id,name,price,tag
1,Zypher,12.50,7:X|9:Y|11:Z
```

tag has two properties dividing by `:`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it using [JSR223 PreProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor) and [Groovy language](http://groovy-lang.org/), something like:

1. Given you have the following CSV file structure:

   ```
   id,name,price,tag
   1,Zypher,12.50,X|Y|Z
   ```
2. And the following [CSV Data Set Config](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) settings:

   [image: JMeter CSV Data Set Congif]
3. Add JSR223 PreProcessor as a child of the [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler and put the following code into "Script" area:

   ```
   import groovy.json.JsonBuilder

   def json = new JsonBuilder()
   def tagsValues = vars.get("tags").split("\\|")

   class Tag {int tag; String tagName }


   List<Tag> tagsList = new ArrayList<>()
   def counter = 1
   tagsValues.each {
       tagsList.add(new Tag(tag: counter, tagName: it))
       counter++
   }

   json {
       id Integer.parseInt(vars.get("id"))
       name vars.get("name")
       price Double.parseDouble(vars.get("price"))
       tags tagsList.collect { tag ->
           ["tag"    : tag.tag,
            "tagName": tag.tagName]
       }

   }

   sampler.addNonEncodedArgument("",json.toPrettyString(),"")
   sampler.setPostBodyRaw(true)
   ```
4. Remove any hard-coded data from the HTTP Request sampler "Body Data" tab (it should be absolutely blank)
5. Run your request - JSON payload should be populated dynamically by the Groovy code:

   [image: JMeter JSON from Groovy]

References:

- [Parsing and producing JSON - Groovy](http://groovy-lang.org/json.html)
- [Groovy Is the New Black](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)

---

Update:

for CSV format

```
id,name,price,tag
1,Zypher,12.50,7:X|9:Y|11:Z
```

Replace the below Groovy code:

```
List<Tag> tagsList = new ArrayList<>()
def counter = 1
tagsValues.each {
    tagsList.add(new Tag(tag: counter, tagName: it))
    counter++
}
```

with

```
List<Tag> tagsList = new ArrayList<>();
tagsValues.each {
    String[] tag = it.split("\\:")
    tagsList.add(new Tag(tag: Integer.parseInt(tag[0]), tagName: tag[1]))
}
```

Comment: Would you please share your jmx? I tried but found my POST Data empty in request.

Comment: And by the way would it be possible to use java or javascript. I am a complete noob in groovy.

Comment: I think the problem is on `def tagsValues = vars.get("tags").split("\\|")` line. Cause I got `Cannot invoke method split() on null object` in log. There is no parameter named `tags` in csv.

Comment: You either need to change `tag` to `tags` in the CSV Data Set Config or vice versa: change the line `def tagsValues = vars.get("tags").split("\\|")` to `def tagsValues = vars.get("tag").split("\\|")` in the Groovy code

Comment: Yes, Thanks already did it. Another thing is you have generated the value of `tag` by using `counter`. How can it be managed by csv file? You know its not incremental always.

Comment: sure, it can be managed via CSV file like other variables, you can access the value from the Groovy script like `vars.get("variable_name_here")`. Groovy is 99.9% compatible with Java so valid Java code will be a valid Groovy code. It is better to avoid using JavaScript as Nashorn scripting engine performance is much worse than Groovy interpreter.

Comment: But that will give me 2 arrays. Suppose 1 for tagList another for tagNameList. How could I assign Tag object's `tag` property from first array & `tagName` property from second array? Question may be noob coz I am new in groovy.

Comment: How does your CSV file look like?

Comment: Got another problem. If I need to set null in JSON what should I keep in csv? I kept empty like X::Z but when I split it it returns "X", ""," Z". For null Integers it is causing problem.

Comment: I made it by condition. Would you give me a way to upload files(Image) while I put file path in csv?